# INSERT with UPDATE on duplicate key

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a query which updates the table or inserts if the row does not already exist, but for some reason it just inserts all the time.

This is my table structure:

```
Id (primary) | uid | product_id | quantity
```

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (uid,product_id,quantity) 
    SELECT t1.uid,?,?
    FROM checker t1
    WHERE t1.id = ?
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    product_id = ?, quantity = quantity+?
```

What i want to do though is use `on duplicate key` if `uid + product_id` combination exist in the table already.

So is there a way to designate what kind of duplication to look for to update instead of insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to distinguish between what duplication occurs.

As soon as *any* unique constraint is violated - it will perform `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part.

For your case you just need to create unique composite key that consists of 2 fields: `(uid, product_id)`

Comment: @Dave: what actually?

Comment: two fields = 1 primary key

Comment: @Dave: I didn't mention primary key in my answer

Comment: oh sorry im so used to primary key being unique that i thought they were the same things.

Comment: you say unique composite but Haim says primary key.. so im bit confused now

Comment: @Dave: I don't see how changing PK for this task is relevant. You determine PK from the problem domain. So what is the PK for this entity (from application domain perspective)?

Comment: well the primary key is just to distinguish each row with a unique auto increment id, its never really used as far as the application is concerned..because i usually look up via two pieces of info user and product

Comment: @Dave: well, my point was: PK should be chosen according the application data model requirements. For this task you need to either create unique key or use PK (if they match). To clarify even more - this task (and honestly - any programming task) isn't a good justification to change PK.

Comment: Well i created a unique key with the two fields. And kept `id` as PK